# How to enter private key password with ansible

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible

I have the vagrant `virtual machine` running.

I can `ssh` into it using `ssh vagrant@192.168.0.28` then it ask me the pass phrase for the private key , which I can enter and then it logs me in.

but if I use:

`ansible all -m ping`

then I get this:

```
192.168.0.28 | FAILED => FAILED: ssh moor@192.168.0.28:22 : Private key file is encrypted
To connect as a different user, use -u <username>.
```

How can I enter pass phrase in ansible?

I tried `ansible -k` but it says authentication failed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `ssh` as the transport. Generally, Ansible uses `paramiko` which is not as friendly for interactive sessions:

```
ansible all -c ssh -m ping
```

If that doesn't work, I didn't see anything on running Ansible with an ssh key pass phrase on the documentation or in the code, so you might have to remove it with something like this:

```
openssl rsa -in private_key_with_pass_phrase -out private_key_without_pass_phrase
```

Comment: i removed the password, but it says authentication failed. how can i mention in ansible that i want to connect via username `vagrant` and not the username of host where i am executing ansible

Comment: you can run `ansible all -c ssh -m ping -u vagrant`

Comment: It's also possible to specify the user you want to login as inside the `/etc/ansible/hosts` file with `ansible_ssh_user=ansible` next to the hostname, or in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` with `remote_user=ansible`. Of course, substituting your desired username instead of `ansible` as I have typed here.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried

```
cd ~/.ssh/
openssl rsa -in id_rsa -out id_rsa_without_pass_phrase
```

and got error

```
unable to load Private Key
routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

solution was to run this command:

```
cd ~/.ssh/
ssh-keygen -p -f id_rsa -m PEM
```