# Git clone hangs in Ansible

Tags: git, ssh, ansible

What I've tried:

1) Copy private key from local machine to server and clone with it:

```
- name: clone repo
  sudo: yes
  git: repo={{ app_repo }} dest={{ app_repo_dir }} accept_hostkey=true key_file={{ssh_key}} version=master force=yes
```

But it hangs. As I understand this issue occurs 'cause key has passphrase.

2) Use `ForwardAgent` in **ansible.cfg**:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

But for connection to server I use not standard ssh `22` port.

How can I setup passphrase for key for `git clone` task in Ansible? Or any other ways to clone remote repository using Ansible?

P.S. Yes, I can try to remove passphrase from key. But security aspects...

Comment: Well, Ansible doesn't has nothing to do with passphrase UU no hope --->  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229688/how-to-enter-private-key-password-with-ansible

Answer (score 1):

1. ~/.ssh/config :

   Host canada.host.xxxx

   HostName canada.host.xxxx

   Port 2233

   User guest

   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.special
  2.

> Copy private key from local machine to server and clone with it:
>
> - name: clone repo   sudo: yes   git: repo={{ app_repo }} dest={{ app_repo_dir }} accept_hostkey=true key_file={{ssh_key}}

This is [Copy private key from local machine to server](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) and clone with it:

```
- name: Put artifact to target
  sudo: yes
  copy: src="{{ app_repo_dir }}" dest="{{ app_repo_dir }}"

- name: clone repo
  sudo: yes
  git: repo={{ app_repo }} dest={{ app_repo_dir }} accept_hostkey=true key_file={{ssh_key}} version=master force=yes
```

PS: 
Maybe you should use [local_action](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#id10)?

ansible-playbook -vvv will show you the problem